# Reverse css-animation on class removal without animation onload

Tags: css, animation

I basically want a transition with one additional step for -webkit-clip-path. 
Only way I know to do that is with css animation.

Click on the menu-trigger adds class `.menuShown` to `body`. The menu reacts to that with an animation. On removal of `.menuShown` the animation should get reversed. 
Only way I know to do that is with animation on the main element.
But this way the animation is triggered on load.

Here is a pen illustrating the problem.
Additionaly I can't get `animation-fill-mode` to work properly in this example.

I almost always use animation / transitions after adding / removing classes and have been wondering how this could be done with actual css animations without the problem of the initial animation.

http://codepen.io/katerlouis/pen/kXZadL

```
.menu {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 30%, 0 30%);
    animation: menuClipPath 2000ms linear;
    animation-direction: reverse;
}

body.menuShown .menu {
    animation: menuClipPath 2000ms linear;
    // animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes menuClipPath {
        0% { -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 30%, 0 30%); }
        50% { -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 0 85%); }
        100% { -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%); }
}
```